# Sharing two SSL wildcard certificates in memory in nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have an nginx server running with two IP addresses, say `1.2.3.4` and `4.3.2.1`. Besides there are two wildcard SSL certificates for `*.example.net` (i.e. `wc1`, pointing to `1.2.3.4`) and `*.sub.example.net` (i.e. `wc2`, pointing to `4.3.2.1`).

The [nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#certificate_with_several_names) mention that you can share a wildcard certificate between `server` instances like this:

```
ssl_certificate      wc1.crt;
ssl_certificate_key  wc1.key;

server {
    listen           1.2.3.4:443;
    server_name      www.example.net;
    ssl              on;
    ...
}

server {
    listen           1.2.3.4:443;
    server_name      test.example.net;
    ssl              on;
    ...
}
```

However, I was wondering whether this same construct is possible to use with the second wildcard certificate too. Both domains have around 500 subdomains.

Do they not get mixed up, since the `ssl_certificate` construct is now global?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
server {
    listen           1.2.3.4:443 default_server ssl;
    server_name      _;
    ssl_certificate      wc1.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  wc1.key;
}

server {
    listen           4.3.2.1:443 default_server ssl;
    server_name      _;
    ssl_certificate      wc2.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  wc2.key;
}

server {
    listen           1.2.3.4:443 ssl;
    server_name      www.example.net;
    ...
}

server {
    listen           1.2.3.4:443 ssl;
    server_name      test.example.net;
    ...
}

server {
    listen           4.3.2.1:443 ssl;
    server_name      www.sub.example.net;
    ...
}

server {
    listen           4.3.2.1:443 ssl;
    server_name      test.sub.example.net;
    ...
}
```

I can affirm that this method definitely works with one wildcard certificate, so here's hoping it works with two or more.

Credit: https://serverfault.com/a/548942/185775

Answer (score 0):

The [`ssl_certificate`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSslModule#ssl_certificate) directive can either be used at the `http` block level (in which case it applies to all `server` blocks), or the `server` level (in which case it only applies to that specific `server` block). If you want to use different certificates just define the `ssl_certificate` inside the appropriate `server` block.

Comment: I only have two certificates, but each certificate is used around 500 times in a subdomain. That's why I wanted to share the memory of the certificate footprint along these 500 subdomains.