# Multiple SSL vhosts using wildcard certificate in nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl, virtualhost, ssl-certificate, https

I have two hostnames sharing the same domain name which I want to serve over HTTPs. I've got a wildcard-SSL certificate and created two vhost configs:

**Host A**

```
listen      127.0.0.1:443 ssl;
server_name     a.example.com;
root        /data/httpd/a.example.com;
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/wildcard.cer;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/wildcard.key;
```

**Host B**

```
listen      127.0.0.1:443 ssl;
server_name     b.example.com;
root        /data/httpd/b.example.com;
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/wildcard.cer;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/wildcard.key;
```

However, I get the same vhost served for either hostname.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to split vhosts from ssl listening/configuration part:

Listening part:

```
server {
  listen              127.0.0.1:443 default_server ssl;
  server_name         _;
  ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/wildcard.cer;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/wildcard.key;
}
```

And now vhosts:

```
server {
  listen      127.0.0.1:443;
  server_name a.example.com;
  root        /data/httpd/a.example.com;
}

server {
  listen      127.0.0.1:443;
  server_name b.example.com;
  root        /data/httpd/b.example.com;
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't work. A vhost needs `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key` that should be configured inside `server` or `http` location. In your example, you have declared it inside the first `server` location, but didn't declare it for the other two vhosts.

Comment: it's enough to configure `ssl_certificate`, `ssl_certificate_key` and `ssl` on default_server only. BTW, this config actually works.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work: nginx serves the same vhost content on both hosts.

Comment: Apparently you need to *restart* nginx instead of *reloading* it when doing these changes. Many thanks, your answer works like a charm :)

Comment: Thanks for this, I needed `ssl` on the `listen` directive for this to work with a 1.4.x nginx.  My `listen` directives in the vhosts also had to be literally the same (logical equivalence was not sufficient).

Answer (score 14):

It's actually explained in the manual:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#certificate_with_several_names

```
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/wildcard.cer;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/wildcard.key;
server {
  listen      443 ssl;
  server_name a.example.com;
  root        /data/httpd/a.example.com;
}
server {
  listen      443 ssl;
  server_name b.example.com;
  root        /data/httpd/b.example.com;
}
```

Now, if you have many sites, I suggest storing all of them in a folder with just the server{} part as above in single files, and an include directive in the main file to load all of them:

```
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/wildcard.cer;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/wildcard.key;
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/subfolder/*;
```