# SSL for multiple servers and sub-domains

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl, wildcard-subdomain

I have purchased a wildcard ssl certificate from RapidSSL and trying to set it up. Essentially I want to be able to use it as:

- `example.com`
- `app.example.com`
- `*.app.example.com`

and that'd be also good if I can use on `staging.app.example.com` on another server (test server).

I have made it work on `app.example.com` but it doesn't work on others.

Also, after doing some reading [this](https://blog.notmyhostna.me/nginx-wildcard-ssl-and-subdomains/) and [that](https://serverfault.com/questions/548938/multiple-ssl-vhosts-using-wildcard-certificate-in-nginx/548942#548942), I have learnt how it is done on definite routes but how about wildcard?

Comment: wildcards are not recursive and I do not believe rapidssl offers multi-wildcard domains. You can check with digicert (who stack exchange uses) or just use something like Letsencrypt and get certs issued on demand for the names you need, up to 100 SANs per cert.

Comment: @JacobEvans In fact, I want the asterisk in `*.app.example.com` to be dynamic such as username. And with this scenario, I won't be able to register a cert for each one of them. What do you think I should do?

Comment: Yes you can absolutely request a wildcard cert for *.app.example.com, I'd still suggest you get an LE cert (wildcard support coming 2018)

Comment: I have already purchased wildcard cert from RapidSSL. In your last comment I realised something: I should register my domain as `*.app.example.com` in the certificate, instead I registered as `*.example.com`, so it only worked on `app.example.com` but not staging. Is that right? But if so, how about `example.com`?

Comment: `example.com` is not covered by `*.example.com` however MANY CAs will add that SAN

Comment: you can likely re-issue the cert with a new CSR containing the proper wildcard domain.

Comment: I will but I am a bit confused. As far as I understand, I should create 3 different ones: `*.app.example.com`, `example.com`, and `*.staging.app.example.com`. Is that right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Most** CA's will issue either a MultiDomain SSL or a single Wildcard cert.

So you would need (2) Certs to cover those 3 domains.

1) `example.com, www.example.com`
2) `app.example.com, *.app.example.com`

staging.app.example.com is covered by `*.app.example.com` but user.staging.app.example.com is not.

I've suggested using `-` hyphens instead in some cases, such as `user-staging.app.example.com`

I say most, as you can request these from Digicert and some others.

**Cert 1 Generation with OpenSSL)**

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -sha256 -keyout example.com.key -subj "/C=US/ST=Virginia/O=Company Name/OU=Web Security/CN=example.com" -config <(
cat <<-EOF
[req]
default_bits = 2048
default_md = sha256
req_extensions = req_ext
distinguished_name = dn
[ dn ]
[ req_ext ]
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = example.com
DNS.2 = www.example.com
EOF
)
```

**Cert 2 Generation with OpenSSL)**

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -sha256 -keyout example.com.key -subj "/C=US/ST=Virginia/O=Company Name/OU=Web Security/CN=example.com" -config <(
cat <<-EOF
[req]
default_bits = 2048
default_md = sha256
req_extensions = req_ext
distinguished_name = dn
[ dn ]
[ req_ext ]
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = app.example.com
DNS.2 = *.app.example.com
EOF
)
```

Comment: And (3) certs if I need to enable `*.staging.app.example.com`?

Comment: yeah, unless you don't use `.` to split out your subdomains and use `-` instead.

Comment: I have a quick question about your answer: Normally, I generate the CSR with `openssl genrsa -out csr.key 2048` command and it was asking me some questions to fill. Your method seemed a bit complex to me. If I am using the answer questions method, in common name, do I need to write `*.app.example.com app.example.com` without any comma or do I write only one of them? [This guide](https://knowledge.rapidssl.com/support/ssl-certificate-support/index?page=content&actp=CROSSLINK&id=SO17540)

Comment: You can do it that way, my one-liner is pretty easy to change the variables to fit your specifics.